# Service ends itself and timer works mysteriously

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, timer

I created an app, which runs as a service. This service starts 2 timers, one that checks every 5 minutes for small config-updates and once per day for great app-updates.
Now I got it to work nearly flawless, except 1 thing, the timers...
When I start the service, the 5 minute-timer runs immediatly instead of waiting 5 minutes. And after this run, the service ends itself. Could someone give me a hint?

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   ServiceBase.Run(new SuiteService());
}
```

The service:

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer _startTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
private readonly DispatcherTimer _shortTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
private readonly DispatcherTimer _longTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread newThread = new Thread(InitializeTimer);
    newThread.Start();
}

private void InitializeTimer()
{
   //// Timer 1
   //_startTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
   //_startTimer.Tick += CompleteProcedure();
   //_startTimer.Start();
   // Timer 2
   _shortTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
   _shortTimer.Tick += MeanwhileCheck;
   _shortTimer.Start();
   // Timer 3
   int milliSeconds = CalculateInterval();
   _longTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milliSeconds);
   _longTimer.Tick += CompleteProcedure();
   _longTimer.Start();
}
```

After this I stop the _longTimer once, do something and start it again, but I never stop the _shortTimer. So my question is:
Why does the app "end"? Shouldn't the Timer keep it alive?

Comment: What is the code inside the MeanwhileCheck and CompleteProcedure event handlers?

Comment: he only checks if specific files exist and if yes, stops some apps, copies some files and starts this apps again. Nothing spectacular.

Comment: Can you check the Event logs to see if an exception is not being handled when you are checking the files and killing the service?

Comment: edit: I added the declaration of the timers (DispatcherTimer).
 
I wrote a complete log of all exceptions thrown, but there is nothing. No entries. I think it has something to do with the threading.

Comment: How do you know the app has "ended"?

Comment: Try to override the **OnStop** and add: **_*Timer.Stop()** and **_*timer.Tick -= Event**

Comment: @DavidG: The process of the app closes (vanishes from the taskmanager) and the service stops.

Comment: @Max: What should it bring to stop the timer and remove the event on stop of the service? The service shall not stop.

Comment: Are you starting the service by running the exe or using services manager?

Comment: @MarcelGrüger agree with you but the event must be detached for cleaning. Anyway can you post the **CompleteProcedure();** and **MeanWhileCheck;** code ?

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I found the bad guy. It was the DispatcherTimer. The DispatcherTimer runs in the UI-thread. But a service doesnt have any UI-threads. So it fired even before the timer started and ended immediately afterwards. After changing it to System.Timers.Timer, and adding an GC.KeepAlive(_shortTimer); it all worked well. :)